# Sample certain number of result rows from a postgres table based on given proportions

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a table named `population` with 1000 rows like the following:

[image]

And I have another table named `proportions` that holds the desired proportions of different `Group_Name`s that I want to extract:

[image]

I want to randomly sample 100 rows from `population` table where the proportions of the `Group_Name`s within the sample is in line with that of the `Proportion` field within `proportions` table. So in that 100 rows sample, 50 rows should be Group-A, 30 rows should be Group-B and 20 rows should be Group-C.
I can manually sample like:

```
CREATE EXTENSION tsm_system_rows;
SELECT * FROM population TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM_ROWS(100);
```

But I do not know how to sample from `population` programmatically based on `proportions` table especially if `proportions` table has a lot more `Group_Name`s than 3 as shown in the example.

Comment: Create a function in postgres which takes number of sample u want as input and calculates the number of rows to return for a each group based on percentage from proportion table and then use your tsm_system_rows clause in select to get random sample and return them.

Comment: Are you expecting a query to do so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sample based on randomly assigned row numbers:

```
select *
from
 (
   select *
     ,case 
        when row_number()
             over (partition by pop.group_name
                   order by random()) <= pr.proportion * 100 -- sample size
        then 1 
        else 0
      end as flag
   from population as pop
   join proportions as pr
   on pop.group_name = pr.group_name
 ) as dt
where flag = 1
```

Edit:

If the table is large creating a SAMPLE before ROW_NUMBER might greatly reduce the number of rows processed. Of course, the SAMPLE size must be large enough to contain at least the required number of rows, i.e. way over 100 rows.

Comment: Technically, you are scanning the whole table and not sampling it. Could cause performance problems.

Comment: @JonathanJacobson: Of course. But when I read the documention *The BERNOULLI method scans the whole table and selects or ignores individual rows independently with the specified probability.* doesn't seem to be better. And SYSTEM is less random.

Comment: @JonathanJacobson gibbz00 should test performance of both solutions

Comment: I can't explain why but `TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI (1) LIMIT 1` is much faster than `ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1`. You can try it on any large table that you have. Perhaps I'll open a question about this subject.

Comment: @JonathanJacobson Well, the ORDER BY RANDOM needs to scan and order the whole table. TABLESAMPLE might be optimized and does not really scan all data. I don't have big tables in PG, my main DBMS is Teradata which supports Stratified Sampling :-)

Comment: The `ORDER BY random()` solution both scans the whole table and runs an expensive sort operation afterwards. I've just fixed my solution so that `TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI` stops after reaching a fixed amount of rows, thus never scanning the whole table. Thank you very much for your feedback.

Comment: @JonathanJacobson Did you ckeck for randomness? When I was running your example from the closed question the rsult was not random, it was heavily biased towards low numbers

Comment: Actually there was a heavy bias before the last edit from 3 hours ago. It should be fine now.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem that you will be facing is that `TABLESAMPLE` takes the sample before applying your group filter. Say that you want 20 rows from group C. The chances of getting those 20 by running

```
SELECT *
FROM population TABLESAMPLE system_rows(20)
WHERE group_name = 'C'
```

are pretty slim if group C is small relative to other groups in `population`.

I'd solve this by writing a stored function that receives as parameters the group name and wanted amount of rows, and samples the table until reaching the wanted amount of rows.

You should also limit the number of iterations, in case that the group is very sparse or there or not enough rows to fulfill the need.

So the function could look like so

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sample_group (p_group_name text, sample_size int, max_iterations int)
RETURNS int[]
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS $$
DECLARE
    result int[];
    i int := 0;
BEGIN
    WHILE i < max_iterations AND coalesce(array_length(result, 1), 0) < sample_size LOOP
        WITH sample AS (
            SELECT group_name, value
            FROM population TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI (1)
            LIMIT 10 * sample_size
        ), add_rows AS (
            SELECT result || array_agg(value) arr
            FROM sample
            WHERE group_name = p_group_name
        )
        SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT value), i + 1
        INTO result, i
        FROM add_rows, unnest(arr) AS t(value);
    END LOOP;

    RETURN result[1:sample_size];
END;
$$;
```

I'm using `BERNOULLI` sampling to avoid getting the same rows over and over.

The function did most of the work for you. All that remains is to call it. In this example I'm setting an upper limit of 500 on the iterations.

```
SELECT group_name, unnest(sample_group(group_name, (100*proportion)::int, 500)) AS value
from proportions;
```